# Symbols not found in architecture + linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, command

I have been cracking my head over this one. I've searched all over and all I seem to find are issues with the same error messages but involving either building complete iphone apps or dealing with header files, all sorts of stuff.

I was just writing a simple C++ program, no header files except the typical iostream, stdlib.h and time.h. This is for a very simple college assignment, but I can't keep working because Xcode gives me this error that has nothing to do with the actual code (based on what I've read). I haven't messed with anything other than the actual .cpp file, I don't even know how I could've messed this up. I've done multiple assignments the same way and have never run into this issue before.

Current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

//functions
void funcion1(int matriz, int renglones, int columnas);
void funcion2(int matriz, int renglones, int columnas);

//variables
int renglones=8;
int columnas=8;
int ** matriz = new int*[renglones];

int main()
{   
    //reservar columnas
    for (int i=0; i < renglones; i++)
    {
        matriz[i] = new int[columnas];
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    funcion1(**matriz, renglones, columnas);
    funcion2(**matriz, renglones, columnas);
}

void funcion1(int **matriz, int renglones, int columnas)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= renglones; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= columnas; x++)
        {
            matriz[y][x] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}

void funcion2(int **matriz, int renglones, int columnas)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= renglones; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= columnas; x++)
        {
            cout << matriz[y][x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Screenshot of error screen
[image: Screenshot of error screen]

EDIT: Fixed code below.

```
void funcion1(int **matriz, int renglones, int columnas)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < renglones; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columnas; x++)
        {
            matriz[y][x] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}

void funcion2(int **matriz, int renglones, int columnas)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < renglones; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columnas; x++)
        {
            cout << matriz[y][x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You failed to supply the `funcion1(int, int, int)` and `funcion2(int, int, int)` functions to the linker.  You're calling them in your main() program, but the linker can't find it.

And no, this does not call your `funcion1(int**, int, int)` function:

```
funcion1(**matriz, renglones, columnas);
```

You are dereferencing the `int**` on two levels, thus yielding an `int`.  Same thing with your call to `funcion2`.

---

To call the  `funcion1(**matriz, renglones, columnas)` function:

```
funcion1(matriz, renglones, columnas);
```

Same thing with `funcion2(int **, int, int);`

```
funcion2(matriz, renglones, columnas);
```

Comment: Thank you! That got rid of the error messages, but now these two lines give me the error "Subscripted value is not and array, pointer or vector"

matriz[y][x] = rand() % 10;

and

cout << matriz[y][x] << " ";

Comment: Exactly which function were you trying to implement?  `funcion1(int**, int, int)` or `funcion1(int, int, int)`?  If it's the second one, and you kept the code the same in the function body, then of course you get an error, since the first parmeter is a plain-old `int`.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it was some other error, something to do with me accesing data i didn't have persission to. Thank you so much!